# Cannot read custom data in firebase notification when sending via SDK

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have an Android app which calls a web service to send messages to us for support.

There is a website which we develop where we can respond to a message and we use Firebase for that. Up until now we were just sending a title and a message like so:

```
var applicationID = "snip";
var senderId = "snip";
WebRequest tRequest = WebRequest.Create("https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send");
tRequest.Method = "post";
tRequest.ContentType = "application/json";

var data = new
{
    to = model.RequestFirebaseID,
    notification = new
    {
        body = model.ResponseMessage,
        title = model.ResponseTitle
    }
};
```

In the Android app I am able to extract the message title using the following Java code

```
String notificationTitle = remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle();
String notificationBody = remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody();
```

However now I am trying to send back a custom field called id,so I amend the code to be

```
var data = new
{
    to = model.RequestFirebaseID,
    notification = new
    {
        body = model.ResponseMessage,
        title = model.ResponseTitle,
        requestid = model.id
    }
};
```

So now when I send a message back to the device using Firebase I have this code to try and read the id field.

```
String messageID = remoteMessage.getData().get("requestid");
```

However this causes ends up as null.

So I have tried testing sending this via the Firebase console, I add requestid to the custom data section and give it a value and the above code is able to read it.

It seems that when I am sending via the web application it cannot see the requestid field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to include the `data` message inside the payload. Something like this:

```
var payload = new
{
    to = model.RequestFirebaseID,
    notification = new
    {
        body = model.ResponseMessage,
        title = model.ResponseTitle
    },
    data = new
    {
        requestid = model.id
    }
};
```

I changed the root variable name to `payload` to distinguish it.

If you add a custom data when using the Firebase Notifications console to send the message, it is included inside a `data` message parameter instead of the `notification` message. See the [Message Types](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#notifications_and_data_messages) documentation for the difference of the two.